# Copying and force overwrite two sub folders

Tags: linux, command, cp

I am have a issue with copying and overwriting two folders.

I can run base folders and everything works fine.

```
cp -rf theme/* /theme2/
```

Above works fine but all i really want to copy is the theme folder like this.

```
cp -rf theme/wp-content/themes/example/* theme2/wp-content/themes/example/
```

The above code wont overwrite and will ask me to confirm each one please help?

Comment: Try like `yes | cp -rf theme/wp-content/themes/example/* theme2/wp-content/themes/example/`

Comment: might be you have an alias somewhere, mapping `cp` to `cp -i`.

Comment: brilliant thanks jayesh yes | cp -rf worked

Comment: sounds strange but using `/bin/cp` instead of cp works for me